# Spark SQL error AnalysisException: cannot resolve column_name

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a common error in Spark SQL, I tried all other answers but no differences!
I want to read the following small CSV file from HDFS (or even local filesystem).

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  id| first_name| last_name|                ssn|      test1| test2| test3| test4| final| grade|
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 4.0|      Dandy|       Jim|        087-75-4321|       47.0|   1.0|  23.0|  36.0|  45.0|    C+|
|13.0|   Elephant|       Ima|        456-71-9012|       45.0|   1.0|  78.0|  88.0|  77.0|    B-|
|14.0|   Franklin|     Benny|        234-56-2890|       50.0|   1.0|  90.0|  80.0|  90.0|    B-|
|15.0|     George|       Boy|        345-67-3901|       40.0|   1.0|  11.0|  -1.0|   4.0|     B|
|16.0|  Heffalump|    Harvey|        632-79-9439|       30.0|   1.0|  20.0|  30.0|  40.0|     C|
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Here is the code:

```
List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(cols, "id, first_name".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(","));
Dataset<Row> temp = spark.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
                .csv(path)
                .selectExpr(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(cols.iterator()).asScala().toSeq());
```

but it errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) 'first_name missing from  last_name#14,      test1#16,id#12, test4#19, ssn#15, test3#18, grade#21, test2#17, final#20, first_name#13 in operator 'Project [id#12, 'first_name];;
'Project [id#12, 'first_name]
+- Relation[id#12, first_name#13, last_name#14, ssn#15,      test1#16, test2#17, test3#18, test4#19, final#20, grade#21] csv
```

In some cases it works without error:

1. If I didn't select anything, it will successfully get all data.
2. If I just select column "id".

Even I tried using *views* and *SQL* method:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("csvFile");
spark.sql(SELECT id, first_name FROM csvFile).show()
```

but I got the same errro!

I did the same with the same data that I read from the database, and it was without any error.

I use Spark `2.2.1`.

Comment: Please include a sample of the file.

Comment: The table at the first part of the question is the whole data on csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of the incorrect structure of the CSV file! I removed the `white spaces` from the CSV file and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

No need to convert String[] --> List<String> --> Seq<String>.

Simply pass array in selectExpr method, because selectExpr support varargs datatype.

```
Dataset<Row> temp = spark.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
                .csv(path)
                .selectExpr("id, first_name".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(","));
```

Comment: Good point to use String[], but I still got the error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`first_name`' given input columns: [ final,       test1,  first_name,  test3, id,  grade,  test2,  ssn,  test4,  last_name]; line 1 pos 0;
'Project [id#12, 'first_name]
+- Relation[id#12, first_name#13, last_name#14, ssn#15,      test1#16, test2#17, test3#18, test4#19, final#20, grade#21] csv`